# Array index out of range when populate tableview from Firebase database

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "items")
            ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                guard let dict = snapshot.value as? NSArray else { return }
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                dict.forEach { (value) in
                    do {

                        let itemData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value,options: .prettyPrinted)
                        let item = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: itemData)
                            self.items.append(item)
                    }
                    catch let err {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
print(self.items) // This 
print(self.items[0]) // works 
            }
```

and trying to access items in tableview:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
itemType = String(describing: (self.items[indexPath.section].item_type)) // terminating with index out of range error
            //...
    }
```

The error occurs because the observe methods work asynchronously and executes later then tableview populates data.

How to solve this ?

Comment: how you are returning number of sections for UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: @Muhammad Afzal for now its constant int for testing purpose func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

Comment: that's the main reason your app crashing you need to return items.count in numberof section of you want to use sections if you want to use rows return number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:::

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "items")
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? NSArray else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            dict.forEach { (value) in
                do {

                    let itemData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value,options: .prettyPrinted)
                    let item = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: itemData)
                        self.items.append(item)
                }
                catch let err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }

            self.yourtableView.reloadData()

            print(self.items) // This 
             print(self.items[0]) // works 
        }
```

And you need to implement numberOfRows at index path method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

and return items.count there.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     itemType = String(describing: (self.items[indexPath.row].item_type)) // terminating with index out of range error
        //...
}
```

Comment: @Jay Good.. but pay attention also to whether you want to use rows as the repeating entity or the sections in your table view.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use numberofsections

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return items.count
  }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
itemType = String(describing: (self.items[indexPath.section].item_type)) 
    }
```

if you want to use numberofrows

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
  }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
itemType = String(describing: (self.items[indexPath.row].item_type)) 
    }
```